# avconv - concat .mp4 without quality loss and huge file size

Tags: video, concatenation, avconv

I am testing out concating mp4 files together and have come across one way to do it that is working but is creating huge file sizes.

my original videos are mp4 and I started out trying to convert them to mpeg after following other guides but found that mpeg would not convert as my file is 1fps and mpeg does not support that.

```
media@v2:~/mp4_test$ avconv -i video1.mp4 video1.mpeg
avconv version 9.16-6:9.16-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Aug 10 2014 18:16:02 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : f4v
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42m4v
    creation_time   : 2014-12-02 13:00:03
  Duration: 00:59:56.90, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 120 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p, 800x600, 120 kb/s, 1 fps, 90k tbn
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-12-02 13:00:03
[mpeg1video @ 0x10c53a0] MPEG1/2 does not support 5/1 fps
Output #0, mpeg, to 'video1.mpeg':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : f4v
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42m4v
    creation_time   : 2014-12-02 13:00:03
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: mpeg1video, yuv420p, 800x600, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 5 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-12-02 13:00:03
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 -> mpeg1video)
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

I read a suggestion to add -r 23.967 for the framerate but that still does not work.

---

I then found that I could convert the files to .avi and concat them successfully.

convert to avi

```
avconv -i video1.mp4 -r 23.967 -qscale 1 video1.avi

avconv -i video2.mp4 -r 23.967 -qscale 1 video2.avi
```

then concat

```
avconv -i concat:video1.avi\|video2.avi -c copy video.mp4
```

Unfortunately this new file is over 1gb when the original is about 50mb. I have tried adjusting the qscale but I just lose too much quality and still can't get the file size down.

is there a good suggestion on what file type I should be converting to first before I can concat them? I don't mind the file size being a bit bigger, but preferably not too much.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind changing the format of the file you can turn them into a single Matroska file by using mkvmerge tool.

The string would be quite simple:

```
mkvmerge -o output.mkv file1.mp4 + file2.mp4
```