# how to Concatenate mp4 or mkv files using avconv

Tags: concatenation, avconv

I have multiple mkv files in a ubuntu directory.I have installed 'avconv' tool and its working fine. My aim is to simple concatenate all those files and produce a single mkv file.
I referenced so many articles and found that this command should serve the purpose:

```
avconv -i "concat:1-1.mkv|1-2.mkv|1-3.mkv" -c copy 1.mkv
```

However, when I run it, I get error:

> concat:1-1.mkv|1-2.mkv|1-3.mkv: No such file or directory

I even tried it with mp4 files but still the same error.

Can anyone point out what wrong I am doing ?
Or there is any other approach ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ffmpeg may turn out to be a [better](https://superuser.com/q/507386/598963) alternative. There is an entire [wiki-page](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate) about concatenation of media files with ffmpeg.

[Alternatively](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29794675/6394138), try the [`mkvmerge`](https://mkvtoolnix.download/doc/mkvmerge.html) utility:

> mkvmerge -o 1.mkv 1-1.mkv + 1-2.mkv + 1-3.mkv

Comment: Thanks, mkvmerge does the job perfectly !

Comment: In case you have a directory of files you want to merge, something like `mkvmerge -o ../merged.mkv $(ls -1 | paste -sd" " | sed 's/ / + /g')` may come in handy (assuming the filenames do not contain spaces).